# How to stop and start Docker container from bash script Synology?

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab, synology

Hey guys so I'm on a synology DS218+ and I'm running docker and hosting my own instance of gitlab in it.

So now I'm trying to write an update Script with bash.

```sh
docker stop gitlab_td3v
rm -rf /volume1/docker/"gitlab"
rm -rf /volume1/gitlab/"gitlab_backup.rb"
cp -r  /volume1/gitlab /volume1/docker/"gitlab"
cp /volume1/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb /volume1/gitlab/"gitlab_backup.rb"
docker rm -f gitlab_td3v
docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
docker run --detach --hostname Myhost.name --name gitlab_td3v --publish ..:.. --publish ..:..  --publish ..:..  --restart always --volume /volume1/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume /volume1/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab --volume /volume1/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

The problem I have now as you can see in the image I'm trying to stop and remove the container but It doesn't recognise it's name, but if I echo  `docker ps` in the file it gives me the container with the name I used in the file.
[CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZUPJ.png)

Also when I just run the commands in the bash shell it works only as soon as I try to run the file it doesn't work and now I'm really confuse cause I made sure I'm on the same user on the same shell and everything and that I am but in the file it won't let me select the container over the name or the id I get from docker ps.

So now the question I guess is did anyone have the same problem or does anyone know a fix for it?

Would really appreciate it thanks.

Comment: Does your script have a shebang line like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. If not, try adding it.

Comment: Added the shebang line sadly didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The script must be executed as root.

```
docker stop CONTAINERNAME
```

CONTAINERNAME is definied by value "NAME"

See by

```
docker stats
```